# Why is there no built-in terminal emulator/console app in Android?

Tags: terminal, default-applications

There should be at least a console accessible since Android uses the Linux kernel.

Why is there no terminal emulator or console **installed by default** in Android OS? Is there a particular reason?

Comment: A console app would be useless. Starting from some Android version (don't know which one) android apps can't list the binaries under /system/bin/ and /system/xbin. They can execute them with absolute path if permissions are correct. So what good is a console app if no commands are available for it to run? Besides, a console app starts becoming slightly useful only when adb client is available on Android (which is not) or the device is rooted. Both are missing in devices, so why bother with a useless console app?

Answer (score 2):

Terminal emulators are developer-level apps, and thus not easily usable app for general users. Consequently, there is no obvious public desire for mobile manufactures to load this app at the time of manufacturing.

Even most users of desktop Linux distributions tent to be inept at terminal usage.

Comment: ok,then what about the console?

Comment: If you are talking about CLI it is same thing, even most of the user don't have the iota of that the android is based upon linux kernel, leave alone the console or terminal. click selfies, chat, use tinder that's it.

Comment: ok about regular users,but there is "developer options" and still no terminal,why?

Answer (score -1):

Use the Android Debug Bridge (https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html)
It's on the PC and you need to connect it. I think it's not necessary to have a "Terminal APP".
For tasks wich need root privilegues, you also need to root the phone.